# How to extend upper and lower limits of ANFIS membership function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to implement ANFIS on MATLAB. My input data operating range is 0-180, but MATLAB generates ANFIS membership function limits within 0-10. How to extend it from 0 to 180?
Also another problem is my ANFIS input data is something like "data = [80 20 40 50 15];" The output membership function does not appear correctly because of input. Please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the **ANFIS toolboc** in MatLab. You can find a description here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/anfis-and-the-anfis-editor-gui.html#FP43334

If your have training data (you need this to train the ANFIS), then the input membership functions will be expanded to the range your data encompass. It is easier to build an ANFIS over this toolbox then typing in the individual commands....
Regards,
Tamas